# Error "can't access property "useEffect", dispatcher is null" only with local npm package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

I am building an own private npm package to outsource some components and functions I need in multiple React Typescript projects.

If I install the package locally with its local path, I receive the following errors:

`Warning: Invalid hook call. [...]` and `can't access property "useEffect", dispatcher is null`

Both the project and the npm package use React 18.2.0 and I am pretty sure that I am not violating the rules of hooks, because as you can see in the following code example it's just a simple useEffect.

**npm package:**

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface ITestProps {}

const Test: React.FunctionComponent<ITestProps> = (props) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("React useEffect hook called...");
  }, []);

  return <div>Test is working.</div>;
};

export default Test;
```

**React Example Project:**

```
import Test from "@xyz/my-package";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Test />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

*The error mentioned above **only appears if I install the npm package locally**. If i `npm publish` it and install it from the npm servers, everything works fine.*

**Possible cause**

After some research I found out that the reason may be that multiple copies of React are used. And indeed, `npm ls react` says that there are multiple React copies used. But I just can't find a way to make it running. I added React to the peerDependencies, but still the same error.

Comment: The "Invalid hook call." error does point out that a likely cause is multiple Reacts.

Comment: @AKX Thanks for your comment. Yes, like I said in the question, that's a cause I found out about myself after some research. And thanks for your help, I found a solution myself already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added React to the peerDependencies, but I never removed it from the devDependencies..

**Possible solution**

After removing React from the `devDependencies`, adding it to the `peerDependencies` and hitting `npm install`, it seems like the package works locally now.

Answer (score 0):

When using pnpm, adding React to `peerDependencies` did not solve the problem for me with a dependency which I had `pnpm link`ed.

Package `a` depended on package `b`. I did `npm link path/to/b` inside of `a`. `pnpm install` created a symlink in `node_modules/react` that pointed to the same location as `node_modules/react`, but I still ended up with two different React objects.

To fix this, I had to add `auto-install-peers=false` to `.npmrc`, and finally I stopped getting a second instance of `React` after importing.